# Does editing unlock voting indefinitely?

Tags: bug, voting

I think that after editing a post, the vote is no longer locked (even after a grace-period).

Assuming that I've got the "edit everything" privilege, I upvote a post. I try to unupvote it after 5 mins. I can't do it as it is "locked". Now, I revise the post (a valid and substantial revision only), allowing me to undo the vote. Then I upvote the post (say, after some time - 15 mins). Seeing the post after several hours, my vote should be locked. However, it isn't locked and I can toggle between upvote, unupvote, downvote, etc.. whenever I wish.

Isn't there some grace period? How long I'm allowed to change my vote?

An example: Today, I revised an upvoted (by me) post: [Can we have a black hole without a singularity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44990) (I just added a tag and changed the HTML to SE's standard linking style). Then, I undid my vote. After a while, I re-upvoted it. Now, I can toggle my vote freely, from upvoted, to no vote, to downvoted. Is this limited only to the editor or can others now vote freely as well?

For some background information, see the **H-bar chat link** where I've discussed this issue with a friend: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7459118#7459118 (Please read all the messages that follow).

Is this by design or a bug?

Comment: So the problem you are reporting is that your vote, after an edit, is not locked even when the graceperiod has passed. Correct?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Yes Martijn. Exactly. Its somewhat difficult to understand my language. Thanks for the response :-)

Comment: To be clear, you edited a post, voted for it, waited _more_ than five minutes and you were able to undo your vote?

Comment: @TinyTimPost: Hi Tim. Not *exactly*. A small add-up before your first line. I've already upvoted the post. I know this is sorta confusing. But still, I require some help :-)

Comment: **For those who can't understand my language (precise one):** I upvote a post. After several hours, I revise it. I undo the upvote. After sometime, I re-upvote it. Now, (even after the grace period), I could trigger the votes again and again. Its not locked...

Comment: Yeah, what I'm trying to ascertain is how long you waited between votes _after_ editing, and the wait between subsequent votes. I'm pretty sure you didn't wait five minutes, and editing re-set the grace period.

Comment: @TinyTimPost: Ok Tim. After editing, I undid the vote simultaneously. After 10 mins, I upvote it again. After several hours (say, some 6 or 7 hours), I undo the vote. **I can undo**. From that, I could trigger my votes :-)

Comment: Alright, clear then. After the edit you can just toggle your votes at will, it failed to lock again. Yes, bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Thank you very much for your revision Martijn...

Comment: Looks like a definite bug, just reproduced it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Ok, if you see it as bug report, then I delete my opinion on that. But some one must be able to change their vote, after some time not easy, but must been able.

Comment: @Aristos sorry, not sure what you mean. One can undo a vote within five minutes from casting it, or after the post was edited. This part work just fine.

Comment: I think you it'd be better if you didn't place that `[status:by-design]` tag so close to the bottom of the post :P I didn't notice at first that it wasn't part of the posts actual tags...