# How does vote lock work -- can someone unupvote answers that are older than 4 years?

Tags: support, locked-votes

I have been receiving several unupvotes on my answers systematically.

The unupvotes appear to be targeting my answers that have garnered more than two or three votes.

These unupvotes seem to be spaced over a week, the latest series being three unupvotes today:

[image: screenshot of reputation history showing three upupvotes today]

I casually chatted in RE.SE chat some time back about the issue, and there it was suggested that I raise the issue here. (Quoting the relevant suggestion from [RE.SE CHAT](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7992/reverse-engineering).)

> still, a question that was not modified/edited for a while has it's
>   vote lock on and therefore users cannot just retract their upvote.
>   Either a user was removed causing all of her upvotes being removed? or
>   something funky happened. Regardless, I cannot think of anything
>   @IgorSkochinsky can do about it. Instead, you may wanna open a
>   question over at meta.stackexchange.com, explicitly focusing on
>   vote-locked posts.

Is something funky happening or are they genuine unupvotes made by someone who feels those answers don't merit their upvotes?

Based on the comments and an answer that was received, it appears vote lock is broken when an edit is done by anyone including a bot run by SO.

If so, doesn't such breaks have a time limit for relocking?
Do they remain open for years together?
Could this behavior be treated as a bug?

**Update**

Just an update and some queries which are based on certain comments and answers:

I received two more unupvotes today

[image]

- again an old post
- again edited but this time the edit was by myself
- and the edits took place within 3 hours of my initial answer 3 years
  ago    as per edit history

[image]

I'm not sure if my answer received a vote within these three hours which was unupvoted - if not, then the vote must have come in after the edit and unupvoted today or it was never voted in first place, but I still lose 10 points.

Is there a possibility to get some hints as to what happened or is happening?

Comment: This is clearly abuse (targeting the person, not the posts), and the RE.SE mods should escalate it to the Stack Exchange Community team to punish the infractor.

Comment: I did a searched for a Q&A on meta about the CU unlocking votes and found nothing, only two circumstances under which it would [unlock posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post/22229#22229). It seems that even if the bot is bumping it shouldn't reset other attributes. You might consider adding the feature-request / bug tag to your question to have this issue corrected. --- It certainly is annoying to lose some points for no apparent reason, especially when two of those answers were accepted, but since they aren't downvotes I don't think they will be reversed.

Comment: Many of your new subquestions are answered here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160876/does-editing-unlock-voting-indefinitely?s=3|47.1572

Comment: Actually, considering the answer you already have, it's unlikely that a staff member would look into this. [I've filed a bug report based on the answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315150/do-not-unlock-votes-if-an-automated-script-edits-a-post), so the bug tag is unnecessary here.

Comment: My bug report has been negatively received, with the top answer saying that if a user abuses automatic edits to unupvote a particular user, that user should be dealt with. I suggest contacting SE regarding this.

Comment: @SonictheInclusiveHedgehog yes i read the thread and the answers already i am not sure if it is a single user abusing  a single target  the latest unupvotes seems to be contradicting as far as i see (not sure if i see right )

Answer (score 9):

Taking your answer to [Disassemble instruction with a variable as an offset](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6433/disassemble-instruction-with-a-variable-as-an-offset/6438#6438) as an example:

- You posted the answer on Oct 13 '14 at 2:20
- It was edited by Community on May 23 '17 at 12:37 ([to replace the http with https](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/6438/revisions))

If the initial upvote came **before** the Community edit then the vote will have been unlocked by that edit. The user is then free to remove that vote (or convert it into a down-vote) at any point from then.

As to why they chose now to do so, I've no idea.

Comment: Good observation. I see that two of the other answers were also edited at some point, but [the answer for *How to set breakpoint on C++ symbols?* never was](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/posts/13359/timeline), and it appears to have also been unupvoted.

Comment: @chrisF yes i noticed that after it was suggested to me in RE SE chat that vote lock breaks if the answer was edited  here is another answer which displays the same behaviour (edit by bot for replacing http to https ) https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3983/how-to-break-on-not-yet-loaded-kernel-driver/3984#3984

Comment: here is a question that took an unupvote  in this case the window between the post and edit seems  to be around 15 days  4 and half years back  https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/3955/how-to-reverse-deviceiocontrol/3965#3965